# How can I rebase as one commit using Git

Tags: git, rebase, squash

My history looks somewhat like this but times 10:

```
                i - j - e'- k - h'- l - m  feature-branch
              /
    a - b - c - d - e - f - g - h  master
```

(the apostrophes meaning cherry picks) 
I want to rebase to this:

```
                                  i - j - k - l - m  feature-branch
                                 / 
    a - b - c - d - e - f - g - h  master
```

I don't mind if the feature gets squashed into 1 commit. The main problem with a regular rebase is that it tries to rebase one commit at a time, and i have to fix and re-fix similar conflicts over and over.

All I want is to take the difference between the tip of my branch and the tip of master and apply those on top of master.

Comment: This would be a lot easier with a regular *merge* instead of a regular rebase.  Additionally, with a merge, the history will be accurate and true instead of containing lies.

Comment: Wait... have you been cherry picking commits from `master` and putting them on `feature-branch`?

Comment: Is `e'` a cherry-pick of `e` and `h'` a cherry-pick of `h`?

Comment: @DietrichEpp: There's nothing wrong with rebasing your local history. It's public history that's the problem. Related: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/255165/is-using-git-stash-as-a-workflow-an-antipattern/255174#255174

Comment: @GregBurghardt: "Nothing wrong" is incorrect, it's just that there are specific problems with rebasing public history that don't apply to private history.  By no means does this mean that there are not other problems with rebasing private history, e.g., your private history could contain unit tests which now break after the rebase, sabotaging future efforts to use `git bisect`.

Comment: @DietrichEpp:  I agree with GregBurghardt.  There are many cases where merging is worse than rebasing not-yet-pushed commits.  Assuming the end result is what was intended, rebasing is just fine.

Comment: @DietrichEpp yes they are cherry picks. does that cause a problem when rebasing?

Comment: Usually cherry picks don't cause problems, but if the other commits on the feature branch touch the same code then you'll get conflicts when you merge or rebase.  There's no way to avoid that—you just have to get good at resolving conflicts.  :)

Comment: Also, it is unusual to cherry pick from `master` to a feature branch, so it can be confusing to others.  Periodically merging `master` into the feature branch is usually preferred.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is actually quite easy.

1. Merge `master` into `feature-branch`.  You will solve all of your merge conflicts here at once.  (I **highly recommend** stopping here.)

   ```
               i - j - e'- k - h'- l - m - n    feature-branch
             /                           /
   a - b - c - d - e - f - g - h --------       master
   ```
2. Then, `git reset --soft master`.  This will make it so that `feature-branch` points at `master`, but it will keep all of your changes in the index, ready to be committed.

   ```
               i - j - e'- k - h'- l - m - n    (orphaned)
             /                           /
   a - b - c - d - e - f - g - h --------       master, feature-branch
                                 \
                                   (index)
   ```
3. `git commit`

   ```
               i - j - e'- k - h'- l - m - n    (orphaned)
             /                           /
   a - b - c - d - e - f - g - h --------       master
                                 \
                                   n'           feature-branch
   ```

The only purpose of #2 and #3 is to destroy the history of `feature-branch`.  If you are certain you will never ever need that history, that's fine.  But it seems like a waste to go to all this extra trouble just to delete an accurate record of what actually happened.

Comment: This isn't the exact behavior I asked for but i did end up doing just step one of this. It allowed one large but manageable conflict resolution stage instead of tons of them. hopefully the fact that its not rebased to look linear doesn't cause any issues in the future.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming `e'` and `h'` are cherry-picks of `e` and `h`, respectively.  I'm also assuming that the conflicts appear when Git tries to apply `e'` and `h'`, but not any of the other commits.  Please correct me if I'm wrong.

You have a few options:

- When `git rebase` drops to a prompt saying that it couldn't apply `e'` or `h'`, run `git rebase --skip` to tell Git to skip that commit.

  Once the rebase is done, if you then want to squash the commits together into one:

  ```
  git reset --soft master
  git commit
  ```
- Do an interactive rebase and tell Git to not apply `e'` and `h'`:

  ```
  git checkout feature-branch
  git rebase -i master
  # Git will launch an editor containing an interactive rebase recipe:
  #   1. Delete the e' and h' lines.
  #   2. Optionally change the j through m lines to 'squash' if you
  #      want to squash all of those commits into one.
  #   3. Save the recipe and exit.
  ```
- `git rebase` is an easier way to do a series of `git cherry-pick` commands.  You can do these commands manually yourself:

  ```
  git checkout -b temp-branch master
  git cherry-pick i j k l m
  # optionally, if you want to squash i through m into a single commit:
  #   git reset --soft master
  #   git commit
  git checkout feature-branch
  git reset --hard temp-branch
  git branch -D temp-branch
  ```